# Can we design inference rules about separation logic in Z3 and use it to proof some props automatically?

Tags: z3, coq, hoare-logic

Can we design inference rules and axioms about separation logic in z3 and use it to proof some props automatically? For example," x=y /\ (x |-> z) |- x=y /\ (y |-> z)"

Comment: Maybe [Why3](http://why3.lri.fr/) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly. Multiple groups are working on separation logic provers based on SMT solvers, or integrated with them. Here are a few recent publications on the topic:

Ruzica Piskac, Thomas Wies, Damien Zufferey: Automating Separation Logic Using SMT. CAV 2013

Matko Botincan, Matthew J. Parkinson, Wolfram Schulte: Separation Logic Verification of C Programs with an SMT Solver. Electr. Notes Theor. Comput. Sci. 254

Juan Antonio Navarro Pérez, Andrey Rybalchenko: Separation Logic Modulo Theories. APLAS 2013

I'm sure there are many other SL provers, but one I know off the top of my head is [SLAyer](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/slayer/).